# .NET and Java producing different signature

Tags: java, .net, cryptography, bouncycastle, signature

I have a sample code in java which I am trying to convert to .NET c# platform. This code encrypts a string and add signature to it. Java code using BouncyCastle provider and the code for adding signature follows.

```
 InputStream in = new FileInputStream(derkeyfilename);
 byte[] privKeyBytes = new byte[in.available()]; 
 in.read(privKeyBytes);
 KeyFactory rsaKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
 PKCS8EncodedKeySpec encodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyBytes);
 private RSAPrivateKey myPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePrivate(encodedKeySpec);

 MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5", "BC");
 byte[] digest = md.digest(msg);
 Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA", "BC");
 sig.initSign(myPrivateKey);
 sig.update(digest);
 byte[] signature = sig.sign();
 byte[] base64 = Base64.encodeBase64(signature);
 String signature = new String(base64);
```

Can anyone help me converting this to c#. I tried few samples (BouncyCastle for C#, openssl etc) and all are returning same signature which is different from what java produces. One more thing I found is java uses .der private key which is not supported in C# (as far as I know). I am using .pem key for the same certificate.

Comment: Your way of reading from an `InputStream` is broken to start with. Personally I never trust `available()` and you should never read from a stream and ignore the return value from `read`. Have you verified whether the digests themselves are the same? How are you getting the bytes from the string to start with? A short but *complete* example would really help - including what you've tried in C#. If multiple .NET approaches are giving the same signature, that's probably the correct one...

Comment: Additionally, you're *only* providing the `Signature` with the MD5 digest... shouldn't you be providing it with the input data (`msg`)?

Comment: @Jon digests are always signed, not the complete data.

Comment: @Eugene: Righto, so actually the business of computing the MD5 sum initially is irrelevant, so long as they give the same results. So the problem can be split into two parts: whether the MD5 sum is computed correctly or not (in which case the signature is irrelevant) and whether the signature for some arbitrary (but equal) MD5-size binary comes out the same.

Comment: You have two different variables called `signature`, one a `byte[]` and one a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't show your C# point, I can only guess what your problem is:

In Java, you are doing a double MD5 hash. Once explicitly in your code, and once implicitly in your `Signature` object (which is defined as `MD5WithRSA`, as you can see). Thus you have here

```
signatureJava = RSA(MD5(MD5(msg)))
```

If you don't do this first MD5 explicitly on the C# side, you there have:

```
signatureC# = RSA(MD5(msg))
```

Obviously these are not the same, unless you have hit a fixpoint of MD5 with your message (very unlikely).

Other than this, are you sure that the C# signature is always the same? As I understand, an RSA signature is ([in the modes normally used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA-PSS#Schemes)) not deterministic, since it incorporates some random padding data.

Comment: +1 Unfortunately, PSS is not the normal mode in Java, it's still RSA with PKCS#1.5 padding.